# Where does a segmentation fault occur if the debugger points to a function definition?

Tags: parsing, c++11, segmentation-fault

To elaborate, I am currently writing a program that requires a function that is provided by the professor. When I run the program, I get a segmentation fault, and the debugger I use (gdb) says that the segmentation fault occurred at the definition of the function that, like I said, was provided by the professor.

So my question here is, is the definition itself causing the fault, or is it somewhere else in the program that called the function causing the fault?

I attempted to find a spot in the program that might have been leading to it, such as areas that might have incorrect parameters. I have not changed the function itself, as it is not supposed to be modified (as per instructions). This is my first time posting a question, so if there is any other information needed, please let me know.

The error thrown is as follows:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. .0x00401450 in Parser::GetNextToken (in=..., line=@0x63fef0: 1) at PA2.cpp:20 20                      return GetNextToken(in, line);

The code itself that this is happening at is this:

```
static LexItem GetNextToken(istream& in, int& line) {
    if( pushed_back ) {
        pushed_back = false;
        return pushed_token;
    }
    return GetNextToken(in, line);
}
```

Comment: Can you include the exact message output by the debugger and the relevant lines of source code?  If you want help actually finding the bug, then reduce your program to a [mcve] and add it to your question.

Comment: The other thing to do is, when the debugger stops and indicates the segfault, run `where` or `bt` to get a full backtrace.  Note that debugging works much better if the program was compiled with `-O0 -g` (assuming gcc or clang which are the common compilers on platforms where gdb runs); optimization can lead to the program appearing to behave strangely under the debugger.

Comment: The function prototype part of a function definition does not ordinarily contain any executable code, so if that's what you mean by "at the definition of the function" then probably either (i) you have misunderstood something, or (ii) the binary being debugged was compiled with optimization enabled, which can confuse the debugger when it tries to match the program counter to a line of source code.

Comment: The error thrown is as follows:


`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
.0x00401450 in Parser::GetNextToken (in=..., line=@0x63fef0: 1) at PA2.cpp:20
20                      return GetNextToken(in, line);`


The code itself that this is happening at is this:


 `static LexItem GetNextToken(istream& in, int& line) {
  if( pushed_back ) {
   pushed_back = false;
   return pushed_token;
  }
  return GetNextToken(in, line);
 }`

Comment: @JP: Please edit the message into your question.  It'll be easier to read and more permanent than as a comment.

Comment: Hard to tell without more details, but it looks like the function is calling itself recursively.  Is it possible that you have infinite recursion?  That would likely cause a segfault when pushing the function's arguments and/or the return address.

Comment: @NateEldredge

Aaah, that'd make sense. Are there anymore details I could add that might help?

Comment: If what you posted is the entire function, then it seems like it recurses infinitely whenever `pushed_back` is false.  If it starts out false then it will not be updated before the next call, so there is no escape from the recursion.  Is that not so?

Comment: You are correct, it was an infinite recursion that was fixed by slightly changing definition names. The mistake was corrected and the code is running now. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Making many assumptions here, but maybe the lesson is to understand how the stack is affected by a function call and parameters.  Create a main() function, that call the professor's provided function and trace the code using dbg, looking at the stack.